# "Having said that" vs. "That being said"

Tags: word-usage

I want to know the meanings of these phrases *Having said that* and *That being said*, the difference between them, and in which context I can use both of them.

According to my first understanding of these expressions, I think they are equivalent to the phrase "Considering what was said before" or in "reference to what has already been said". I am not sure of the meaning, but hope to find its exact meaning.

Comment: Have you done any research on these two phrases?  They are fairly equivalent in usage.  If you have looked them up and are still confused as to their meaning, you should post what you believe them to mean, and why you feel there is a difference.  (In other words, please show your work.)

Comment: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1807

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are both well-understood idioms, mostly used in a context in which you are about to state a paradox, or contradiction, e.g.:

John failed all his A levels. But *having said that* he is highly literate in matters of IT and has found a well paid job immediately.

England are underdogs for their opening World Cup fixture against Italy. *That being said* it is not unknown for the Italians to lose an opening match against ranked outsiders, such as when they were beaten by Ireland in New York in 1994.

Both of them mean, and could easily be replaced with **'Notwithstanding that...'**

Answer (score -1):

They are pretty literal.  *Having said that* is usually followed by a clause with the speaker of *that* as the subject.

> "Having said that, *I* think ..." OR
>   "Having said that, *he* sat down again..."

"That being said" doesn't have any implications on who said it.

Comment: Why do you think so? Is that an opinion?

Comment: "Having said that, he sat down again..." would admittedly usually be taken to mean "When he had finished what he had to say, he sat down again". The 'comment clause' sense, which is what OP is talking about, is, on the other hand, a pragmatic device: extra to the propositional material. "He waited impatiently for Sally to arrive, and suddenly dashed to the window to look, seemingly unable to contain himself. Having said that, he sat down again for another five minutes."

Comment: @Kris- I suppose it's an opinion formed after some consideration.  I considered the case of: "*Susan stood up and remarked, 'I don't think he likes me at all. That being said, he did open the door for me the other day.'*"  As well as the case of "*Susan stood up and remarked, 'I don't think he likes me at all.' 'That being said, he did open the door for you the other day,' said John.*"  I therefore concluded that it can be used in either situation and thus can't have any implications in and of itself as to the speaker; just that it *was* spoken (or written).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- I suppose, but that mixes the narration and the story in a way that goes against the grain for me.